# C# How to GroupBy so that an item can be put into multiple groups

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, grouping

I have a bunch of articles and I want to organize them by category. This would be simple with a GroupBy(x => x.Category), except that some articles have multiple categories. How can I group my articles so that if they have two categories, they are put into both category groupings?

example:

```
Article 1, category:apples, oranges
Article 2, category:apples
Article 3, cateogry:oranges
```

I would end up with two categories, apples and oranges:

```
apples: Article 1, Article 2
orange: Article 1, Article 3
```

Comment: Maybe you want to share some samples, your code and the expected output with us

Comment: I added an example of what I'm looking for

Comment: Execute `GroupBy` for every category.

Comment: I don't necessarily know what my categories are before running this, they're dynamic. I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do this

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your problem correctly, you can do the following:

```
var groups = 
    products.SelectMany(p => p.Categories,
                        (p, c) => new { Product = p, Category = c })
            .GroupBy(p => p.Category, p => p.Product);
```

The relevant `SelectMany` overload is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx).

The equivalent query syntax is much nicer:

```
var groups = from p in products
             from c in p.Categories
             group p by c into g
             select g;
```

Thanks to [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500902/767890) for pointing out the obvious way to translate the fluent version to the query syntax one (I was trying to convert it way too literally).

Answer (score 0):

```
var categories = articles.selectMany(x => x.categoies).Distinct().Select(x => {
  var categoriziedArticles = articles.Where(z => z.cagories.Conains(x)));
  return new Category(categoriziedArticles);
});
```

Maybe something like this.  I have not tried compiling this.