# Equivalent linq query syntax

Tags: c#, linq

What is the equivalent query syntax for the following overload of `GroupBy`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> 
   GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
      this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
      Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
      Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector
)
```

This question cropped up when trying to write the equivalent query syntax of the following:

```
var groups = 
    products.SelectMany(p => p.Categories,
                    (p, c) => new { Product = p, Category = c })
            .GroupBy(p => p.Category, p => p.Product);
```

The "normal" query syntax would give back redundant information: `Category` already given by the `Key` property:

```
var groups = from p in products
             from c in p.Categories
             let pc = new { Product = p, Category = c }
             group pc by pc.Category into g
             select g;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var groups = 
    products.SelectMany(p => p.Categories,
                    (p, c) => new { Product = p, Category = c })
            .GroupBy(p => p.Category);
```

This issue cropped up while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49499885/767890).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression between `group` and `by` is the element selector.  You went out of your way to *add* the information you specifically don't want into that element.  You just need to...not do that.

```
var groups = from product in products
             from category in product.Categories
             group product by category into g
             select g;
```

Comment: oh god, I feel dumb. Thanks